# What does "be true of" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

What does "be true of" mean in the following context?

> There is a debate in the literature on properties between the abundant conception of properties **(**, according to which there is a property corresponding to every natural language predicate and, more generally, every class of individuals,**)** and the sparse conception of properties **(** , according to which a predicate expresses a property only if the objects that predicate **is true of** resemble one another in an intrinsic way **)** .

p.s. The above sentence is quite long, so I get the structure across with brackets. Please feel free to point out if I make any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abundance is not a property of the *clarity* property of that sentence.

We know that the verb *resemble* is plural and so its subject must be "the objects".

**According to the "sparse" conception of properties, a predicate expresses a property only if the objects which can be said to have that property resemble one another in an intrinsic way.**

"the objects that predicate is true of" = the objects that can (truly) be said to be characterized by that predicate, i.e. truly have the predicated property.

Skyscrapers are tall. Is *tallness* **true of** skyscrapers? Yes, tallness **is a characteristic of** skyscrapers.

P.S. When we say that "a property or characteristic is *true of* something" we mean that the something does have that characteristic.  The characteristic can be expressed adjectivally (a predicate adjective) or by a verb. Consider:

**Birds can fly.**

While that capability is *true of* most birds, it is *not true of* all birds. The emu and the ostrich cannot fly.

**The emu is flightless.**

**The emu is a flightless bird.**

**The emu cannot fly.**

*Flightlessness* is a property or characteristic *of* the emu.

Comment: So `tallness` is a property, `skyscraper` is an object, and that is the reason we use `of` here (property of object) , right?

Comment: Yes, you have it.